# Issue with in operator in Delphi 64 bits project

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe2

I'm porting a Delphi project to 64 bits and I have a problem with a line of code which has the `IN` operator.

The compiler raise this error

> E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Int64'

I wrote this sample app to replicate the problem.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;


Var
 I : Integer;
 L : Array of string;
begin
  try
     if I in [0, High(L)] then


  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

This code works ok in 32 bits, but why doesn't it compile in Delphi XE2 64 bits? How I can fix this issue?

***UPDATE ***

It seems which my post caused a lot of confusion (sorry for that) , just for explain the original code which i'm porting is  more complex, and I just wrote this code as a sample to illustrate the issue. the original code uses an in operator to check if a value (minor than 255) belongs to a group of values (all minor or equal to 255) like so

```
i in [0,1,3,50,60,70,80,127,High(LArray)]
```

Comment: You may consider the faster `cardinal(I)<=cardinal(high(L))` which will make the comparison with only one opcode, and solve the type-casting issue.

Comment: You should be very careful to make sure `High(LArray) <= 255`

Comment: @Arnaud What makes you think that performance is so important? Why would you prefer to use cryptic hard to read code with hidden nuance and range errors? That makes no sense to me. Looks like a classic case of premature optimisation.

Comment: @salvador If you are going to use sets in this way make sure your code contains an assertion that `high(L)>=low(Byte)` and `high(L)<=high(Byte)` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code can't be compiled because the [`High`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.High) function is returning a 8 byte value, which is not a ordinal value. and the In operator can be only used in sets with ordinal values.

FYI, the size of the results returned by the High function is different depending of the parameter passed as argument.

Check this sample

```
 Writeln(SizeOf(High(Byte)));
 Writeln(SizeOf(High(Char)));
 Writeln(SizeOf(High(Word)));
 Writeln(SizeOf(High(Integer)));
 Writeln(SizeOf(High(NativeInt)));
 Writeln(SizeOf(High(TBytes)));
```

Finally, you can fix your code casting the result of High function to integer.

```
 if I in [0, Integer(High(L))] then
```

**UPDATE**

Check the additional info provided by David and remember to be very careful when you use the `in` operator to check the membership of a value in set with variable values. The `in` operator only checks the least significant byte of each element (in delphi 32 bits).

Check this sample

```
  i:=257;
  Writeln( 1 in [i]);
```

This return true because the low byte of 257 is 1.

And in Delphi 64 bits, the values greater than 255 are removed of the set. So this code

```
  i:=257;
  Writeln( 1 in [i]);
```

will return false because is equivalent to

```
  Writeln( 1 in []);
```

Comment: If you use High, you should also use Low. Hard-coding a 0 may work, but using Low always works.

Comment: According to the docs sets must have a base type no bigger than 256 elements. So can [0..integer(high(L))] even work?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `[0..integer(high(L))]` is not equal to `[0,integer(high(L))]`

Comment: @Krom, the `InRange` function test if a Value is  between a min and max value, so in this case is not applicable because `if I in [0, Integer(High(L))] then` is equivalent to wrote `if (i=0) or (i=Integer(High(L))) then `

Comment: Would not testing (i=0) or (i=High(L)) would be more correct than IN operator in this case?

Comment: @RRUZ I've corrected my answer. I don't like the cast although I suspect you wrote it to illustrate the issue of ordinal types and sets rather than to recommend its use in real code. I felt that was important enough to spell out in an answer. I hope you aren't offended!

Comment: @Krom, maybe for check two values, but for multiple values the IN operator is very usefull, for example `MyValue IN [1,3,4,6..20]`

Comment: @Krom In my view `in` is much more readable, but the cast is untenable.

Comment: @RRUZ: I had some issues in using IN like that in Delphi7. Is it safe to use it like that in e.g. XE2? I mean `I in [-5, 45, $FFFF, 4000000000]` cases

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not problem :), as you say I focus my answer in explain the issue and suggest  quick fix`. Personally I prefear use the `IN` operator than write a `if` sentene with multiples `or`

Comment: @RRUZ: Plz see Sergs answer, is it still correct for XE2 64bit?

Comment: @RRUZ see my latest update. The `in` operator is simply not fit for purpose here.

Comment: Or perhaps faster `cardinal(I)<=cardinal(high(L))` which will make the comparison with only one opcode, and solve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

What RRUZ says is quite correct.

To add a little bit more explanation, in 64 bit Delphi, dynamic array indices can be 64 bits wide. This is clearly needed, for example, when working with a large TBytes memory block. And so the `high` function must return a value of a type wide enough to hold all possible indices. So, `high` when applied to a dynamic array, returns a value of type `Int64`.

Once you start compiling 64 bit code the `in` operator is unsuited to the problem you are trying to solve. Whilst you could use the cast that RRUZ suggests, it may be clearer to write the code like this

```
if (I=low(L)) or (I=high(L)) then
```

Whilst the `in` operator makes for quite readable code, it is my opinion that a cast to `Integer` is not acceptable here. That will simply set a trap for you to fall into when you first have an array with more than `high(Integer)` elements. When that happens the code with the cast will stop working.

But in fact the problems run far deeper than this. The `in` version of the code fails long before you reach `high(Integer)` elements. It turns out that your code, whilst it compiles, does not really work. For example, consider this program:

```
program WeirdSets;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  SysUtils;
var
  a: array of Integer;
begin
  SetLength(a, 257);
  Writeln(BoolToStr(Length(a) in [0, Length(a)], True));
end.
```

You would expect this program to output `True` but in fact it outputs `False`. If instead you were to write

```
Writeln(BoolToStr(Length(a) in [0, 257], True));
```

then the compiler reports:

```
[DCC Error] WeirdSets.dpr(9): E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds
```

The fundamental issue here is that sets are limited to 256 elements so as soon as you have an array with length greater than that, your code stops working.

Sadly, Delphi's support for sets is simply inadequate and is in urgent need of attention.

---

I also wonder whether you actually meant to write

```
if I in [0..High(L)] then
```

If so then I would recommend that you use the `InRange` function from `Math`.

```
if InRange(I, 0, High(L)) then
```

or even better

```
if InRange(I, low(L), High(L)) then
```

Comment: Very good to have this sorted out at last. You deserve more upvotes for truly correct and in-depth answer )

Comment: +1 good answer David, I updated my answer too with more info about the In operator.

Answer (score 2):

The most serious problem with the OP code is that `in` operator is limited to `set` size, i.e. [0..255]. Try this in any 32 bit version of Delphi to avoid the 64 bit issue:

```
var
  I: Integer;
  L: array of Integer;

begin
  SetLength(L, 1000);
  I:= 999;
  Assert(I in [0, High(L)]);  // fails !
end;
```

The OP is lucky if `Length(L) <= 256` always, otherwise it is a bug you probably never thought of.

To find this bug switch range checking on:

```
{$R+}
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  A: array of Integer;

begin
  SetLength(A, 1000);
  I:= 999;
  if I in [0, High(A)] then ShowMessage('OK!');  // Project .. raised exception
                          // class ERangeError with message 'Range check error'.
end;
```

Comment: @LU RD - No typos, `Length(L) <= 256` ==> `High(L) <= 255` if you mean it.

Comment: Sorry, mixed up high and length.